# Making http stream to be https

Tags: web, streaming, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on Alexa skill to stream some custom radio stations. The issue is that Amazon requires `HTTPS` for the stream but some of radios stream over `HTTP` only. I'm considering what are options and would be glad if you know about some other options.

My list is,

- Creating an HTTPS website that gets the original HTTP stream and sends it over. This however seem costly. It'd be nice if there was such a website hosted by somebody
- I don't have much other ideas

(I should say that I'm not maintaining the radios so I can't influence the protocol they use.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue: You can create a **m3u** file which is reachable via https. You could do via Amazon S3 bucket or more simple via github gist.

I did the following:

- http://lokruf.onlinestream.de/listen1.m3u does not have https
- I created this [file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/timguy/8943308c5a45cae6f22aed3e64a0c6b8/raw/50f5d41c7e07add9777785c334fc513a650e84b9/streamLokruf.m3u) with only one line as content: `http://lokruf.onlinestream.de/listen1.m3u`
- I used this gist https link in my skill for radio streaming instead the original http one
- an other example I had:

  - for this stream http://64.71.79.181:5238/stream
  - I created: https://gist.github.com/timguy/cc67df71e36e0698cf81084ce9f3488b
  - and used the raw link in my skill: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/timguy/cc67df71e36e0698cf81084ce9f3488b/raw/37c995873528f85c311293dd9f3136657e98c730/radioroberto.m3u